# Model building on sensors data to toggle a switch to on/off state automatically

Tags: machine-learning

Say I have sensor data from a hardware which senses every 100ms. Now a switch is automatically turned on based on some set of features of the device and then again gets turn off based on the values of those features again.

I have build a model which looks only in the sensor data in the vicinity(by time) of turning on trigger point(as 1 output data) and same for turning off point as well(as 0 output data).
But the classifier works very poorly . It detect turn on point randomly and never turns off, and some times totally misses a on/off cycle.
Any suggestions on how to attack these kinds of problems?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons associated with the failure.  I do not know what hardware or software that is being employed for the problem, but here are a few that may come to mind:

**Timing** - Perhaps there is some delay in your system

**Algorithm** - Perhaps there is something that is incorrect in your code that is causing random behavior in the system.

**Wiring** - Perhaps there is something that is sending the wrong signals.

The best way to attack these problems is to try and break the system down and test each individual component.  This way, you may be able to diagnose the fault and resolve the issue.

Good luck!